# Javascript Checkbox Validation when Text Field has a value

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I'm trying to work the code below. Basically, what I need is to have an alert if the text field (dateshipped) is not empty and the checkbox (close) is not checked. So if both are empty, the form can submit, but if the text field has a value, and the checkbox is not checked, then the alert. And the alert should have the option to Continue or Cancel.

```
<script>
function validate() {
    var valid = true;
    var checkbox = document.getElementById('close').value;
    var text = document.getElementById('dateshipped').value;
    if(!(checkbox || text))
        valid = confirm("Checkbox isn't checked. \n Continue?");
    return valid;
}
</script>
```

My form:

```
<form id="form" name="form" method="post" onsubmit="return validate();">
<input type="checkbox" name="close" id="close" value="Yes"><label for="close" class="css-label-rma" title="Close this">Close this</label>
<input type="text" name="dateshipped" id="dateshipped" class="datefield" /></label>
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Here's the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jvvu6vo0/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid you have a couple of problems

1) `onsubmit` is a form event and not a `button` event. You should have

```
<form id="form" name="form" method="post" onsubmit="return validate();">
```

2) function `validateSubmit` doesn't exist. The name id `validate`

3) Your submit button must be of type `submit`

4) You have to use checked property instead of value

```
document.getElementById('close').checked;
```

Comment: ok, I made the corrections, but the form submits anyway. Again, I need to get an alert only if the text field has a value and the checkbox is not checked. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Brasciole: see this jsfiddler to see if that's what you want http://jsfiddle.net/j7e8tb29/

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to change the type of your button to `submit`.
2. Check when form is submitted.
3. Run the validate method withing that check.

You have a few errors in you `validate` function. You should check for `checkbox.checked` instead of `checkbox.value` and you should check the length of your string for your `text`.

[This fiddle should work for you.](http://jsfiddle.net/jvvu6vo0/19/)

```js
function validate() {
    var valid = true;
    var checkbox = document.getElementById('close');
    var text = document.getElementById('dateshipped').value;
    if( ! checkbox.checked || text.length)
        valid = confirm("Checkbox and text are empty. \n Continue?");
    return valid;
}

var form = document.getElementById('form');
form.onsubmit = function(e) {
    if ( ! validate()) {
        e.preventDefault(); // This will stop the form from submitting.
        return false;
    }

    alert('I am submitted.');
}
```

```html
<form id="form" name="form" method="post">
<input type="checkbox" name="close" id="close" value="Yes"><label for="close" class="css-label-rma" title="Close this">Close this</label>
<input type="text" name="dateshipped" id="dateshipped" class="datefield" /></label>
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```